# What does the circle with dots mean?

Tags: applications

I have this circle with dots that showing up on my apps. Where did it come from and how do I get rid of it?

I've attached some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

It sort of floats on top of it. I can move it around but it doesn't seem to respond to anything.

Disclaimer: I wrote the [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.AsciiArtMaker) shown but I don't know where this came from and I don't see it on other apps.

Comment: Keep your app opened and force-stop all the apps having the permission to draw over other apps. If that icon still stays where it is now, then your app is  what causing that icon.

Comment: Let me guess. Your phone is Samsung S5 or Note 4? That is the Toolbox.

Comment: Yes I have a Samsung Galaxy 6. What is this tool box you speak of?

Answer (score 1):

It's either **Floating Toolbox (Floating Launcher)**  which is a shortcut application or the **Samsung Galaxy S5/S6 Toolbox**. These
`Floating Toolbox` apps gives you access to your apps from anywhere by pressing the Floating button.

Here is a link to the Floating toolbox app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toolbox.shortcuts

You should be able to disable / uninstall them from settings -> application manager.

Comment: I don't see anything running. I checked accessibility as well. I have action launcher but it's not running. Going to uninstall it.

Comment: I would believe it's a Samsung thing but it doesn't respond to any interaction except moving it around the screen.

Comment: I've been reading on the Galaxy S5 Toolbox I'm sure it's that but all the articles I've read on it say it can be accessed in the settings under Toolbox or other locations but it's nowhere to be found. So I think it's been renamed, moved or integrated into the OS or something like that. I do think it's a bug though because it only appears on one app so far.

Answer (score 0):

That icon is definitely the same than the toolbox one, if it's not for that, then the only logic explanation is that something was activated on the Accessibility options, is the only place now where all this hidden features should be enabled, so I'm guessing the OP should have unintentionally turned on one of this settings, OP, were you playing on the Accessibility menu by any chance? If so, do you remember what you were doing?

Comment: I don't remember changing anything

Comment: Well, I am pretty sure that the toolbox is the problem. Some others have this as well. Can you still do stuff?

Comment: Yeah. It just floats above the app. I can move it around. No other interactions though. I couldn't find a way to uninstall or disable it.

Comment: Reason Solved* When you press the 3 dots, you should be able to see info about the app

Comment: On the app I'm using it does nothing but another app I used it did something but I don't remember what it was. I didn't have time to make a note of it at the time. I couldn't find the programs mentioned. It doesn't mean they aren't installed but I'm wondering if it's a Adobe AIR thing.